# Regular expression 1 or two letters followed by decimal number

Tags: regex, string, numbers

I need a regex to match the 1 or 2 characters (just these 4: 'C', 'D', 'RC', 'RD') following by decimal number in the middle of the whole string (in bold), for ex.:

8372**C8932,25**adfadf

82912**RC839,00**klsd

87**D74,23**lsdf

97571**RD876,55**adsf

I tried this but maybe there is a better solution?

```
[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
R?[CD]\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kXqaKV/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `R?[CD]`: Match optional `R` followed by `C` or `D`
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `(?:[,.]\d+)?`: Optionally match `,` or `.` followed by 1+ digits